# Is this an iPhone UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, controls

JotNot has a screen that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceakE.jpg). It's similar to the built-in Photos app when you are viewing a photo in landscape mode and click on the low-left button, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wGqI.jpg).

How do I get this control, in portrait mode if possible? What is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a `UIActionSheet` that has too many buttons to fit on the UI.

When there are too many buttons, `UIActionSheet` uses a stylised table view to display the choices. You can't make the sheet display in this way by choice - it only displays if there are too many buttons to show at one time (which is why it is often seen in landscape mode).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an UIActionSheet, it has a list of buttons like a tableview when all buttons can not displayed at the same time on the screen.