# iOS below 7.0 shows grouping of button on UIActionsheet in Landscape mode

Tags: ios, xcode4, uibutton, landscape, uiactionsheet

I have five UIButtons displayed in UIActionsheet. This is displayed fine in portrait-mode. However, in case of landscape-mode all UIButtons are grouped together and presented by iOS (6.1.3) as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Also, the console displays following message :

**Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. On iPhone try -[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:] or -[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:] instead of -[UIActionSheet showInView:].**

I would like to know the reason and possible solution to avoid it.

Comment: Want to avoid it? use less buttons...

Comment: @TussLászló All five buttons are mandatory as per requirement. I think lootsch answered my question.

Comment: Yes he did. With `UIActionSheet`, you have no other choice than let it handle the display. Maybe consider using something else if its really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Landscape/Portrait issue. This will happen in portrait mode as well, if you add enough buttons.

> That is a UIActionSheet that has too many buttons to fit on the UI.
>
> When there are too many buttons, UIActionSheet uses a stylised table
>   view to display the choices. You can't make the sheet display in this
>   way by choice - it only displays if there are too many buttons to show
>   at one time (which is why it is often seen in landscape mode).

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192467/2115477)